# Unit testing on implementation-specific database usage

Tags: python, database, unit-testing

I'm trying to create unit tests for a function that uses database queries in its implementation. My understanding of unit testing is that you shouldn't be using outside resources such as databases for unit testing, and you should just create mock objects essentially hard coding the results of the queries.

However, in this case, the queries are implementation specific, and if the implementation would change, so would the queries. My understanding is also that unit testing is very useful because it essentially allows you to change the implementation of your code whenever you want while being sure it still works.

In this case, would it be better to create a database for testing purposes, or to make the testing tailored to this specific implementation and change the test code if we ever change the implementation?

Comment: What do you want to test? That the sql works or that the correct 'version' of the sql would be executed?

Comment: Basically, I want to test that the end result is the same. What the function itself does, is query the database for some data, and use a bit of logic on that data to get a result. However, it's possible to do the same task with a different query and different logic (the case I'm looking at right now is using 2 SELECT *'s vs a SELECT * with a LEFT JOIN) , so I want to ideally account for that while writing the tests.

Comment: Hard to say from here, is the 'bit of logic code' common? The place I'd try to get to is the sql in some sort of resource file, chosen by dbms/version. without that, this is going to be a major pain in the posterior.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, so what you're saying is decide on the queries I'll use for each dbms/version, and then create my tests to be specific for each of those queries (based on dbms/version as well)?

Comment: if you want to test the query, yes. Did I get it wrong I thought you had different queries because of different dbms's?

Comment: Yeah, the code currently only uses a single set of queries, but the current code is probably not the most efficient way of doing things and I want to account for the code changing due to us finding more efficient ways of doing things in the future. I've decided it makes more sense to have a test database in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to start with, I think this is very much something that depends on the application context, the QA/dev's skill set & preferences.  So, what I think is right may not be right for others.

Having said that...

In my case, I have a system where an extremely complex ERP database, which I dont control, is very much in the driver's seat and my code is a viewer/observer, rather than a driver of that database.  I don't, and can't really, use an ORM layer much, all my added value is in queries that deeply understand the underlying database data model.  Note also that I am mostly a viewer of that db, in fact my code has read-only access to the primary db.  It does have write access to its own tagging database which uses the Django ORM and testing there is different in nature because of my reliance on the ORM.

**For me, it had better be tested with the database.**

*Mock objects?*  Please, mocking would have guzzled time if there is a lot of legitimate reasons to view/modify database contents with complex queries.

*Changing queries*.  In my case, changing and tweaking those queries, which are the core of my application logic, is very often needed.  So I need to make fully sure that they perform as intended against real data.

*Multi-platform concerns*.  I started coding on postgresql, tweaked my connectivity libraries to support Oracle as well.  Ran the unit tests and fixed anything that popped up as an error.  Would a database abstraction have identified things like the LIMIT clause handling in Oracle?

*Versioning*.  Again, I am not the master of the database.  So, as versions change, I need to hook up my code to it.  The unit testing is invaluable, but that's because it hits the raw db.

*Test robustness*.  One lesson I learned along the way is to uncouple the test from the test db.  Say you want to test a function that flags active customers that have not ordered anything in a year.  My initial test approach involved manual lookups in the test database, find CUST701 to be a match to the condition.  Then call my function and test if CUST701 is the result set of customers needing review.  Wrong approach.  What you want to do is to write, in your test, a query that finds active customers that have not ordered anything in a year.  No hardcoded CUST701s at all, but your test query query can be as hardcoded as you want - in fact, it should look as little as your application queries as possible - you don't want your test sql to replicate what could potentially be a bug in your production code.  Once you have dynamically identified a target customer meeting the criteria, then call your code under test and see if the results are as expected.  Make sure your coverage tools identify when you've been missing test scenarios and plug those holes in the test db.

*BDD*.  To a large extent, I am starting to approach testing from a BDD perspective, rather than a low-level TDD.  So, I will be calling the url that handles the inactive customer lists, not testing individual functions.  If the overall result is OK and I have enough coverage, I am OK, without wondering about the detailed low-level to and fro.  So factor this as well in qualifying my answer.

*Coders have always had test databases.*  To me, it seems logical to leverage them for BDD/unit-testing, rather than pretending they don't exist.  **But I am at heart a SQL coder that knows Python very well, not a Python expert who happens to dabble in SQL.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I thought as well. About the test robustness, what you mean is to have a test database and have the test query it for the expected result you're looking for, rather than have it hard coded in the test (because then changing the test database would not change the expected result), right?

Comment: Correct.  That is a key point - write a test query to identify test criteria and expectations, then call your code against that dynamically determined set of input parameters.  Run your assertions against the also dynamically looked up expectations.  If you don't do that, you will end up with really brittle tests and you will end up in the "mock/dont db" testing camp.

Comment: What if the easiest way to get the expected results for one of the unit tests is the code that is already currently being used. Would you then hard code the expected results, or would you basically copy over the code (since you know the current code works) in order to catch mistakes made when changing the code?

Comment: you need to weigh the pros/cons.  if you use your app logic to figure out what the unit tests should be doing, you risk relying on an invalid function to test another.  and you most certainly shouldn't use the query under test to test itself.  if you must reuse an app query to figure out your testing, make sure that test-building query is tested independently.  in doubt, i would err on the hardcoding end, possibly with cleanup later on, rather than building tests on app logic.  keep in mind:  "easiest" is not necessarily always best.

Comment: also, if you are talking about computing expected results, rather than identifying rows of data to test, then i would *not* do that.  take a simple case to start with & code a naive Python calculation of the results from the fetched data in the unit test, don't rely on the app's queries to do calculations.   again, i can see mucho problems coming out of relying on app code to test the same app code. start with something simple, get a feel for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems I got the wrong end of the stick, I had a similarish problem and like you an ORM was not an option.

The way I addressed it was with simple collections of Data Transfer objects. 
So the new code I wrote, had no direct access to the db. It did everything with simple lists of objects. All the business logic and ui could be tested without the db.

Then I had an other module that did nothing but read and write to the db, to and from my collections of objects. It was a poor mans ORM basically, a lot of donkey work. 
Testing was run the db creation script, then some test helper code to populate the db with data I needed for each test.

Boring but effective, and you can with a bit of care, refactor it in to the code base without too much risk.